# Eloquent query giving data from the wrong row

Tags: laravel, eloquent

A while ago I started my first project with Larvel, and came across this weird issue with a Elequent query I had.

So I have 3 tables:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       storage       |       items      | storage_contents |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         id          |        id        |        id        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       user_id       |       name       |    storage_id    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        name         |    description   |     item_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     description     |       kcal       |      amount      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                     |      img_url     |    expiry_date   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                     |  always_on_list  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Where storages belong to users, storages contain items, and storage_contents being the pivot table between those two.

If anybody is wondering why I didn't just put `expiry_date` and `amount` in the `Items` table but in their own pivot table, that is because I intended to make it so users could use each other's items in their own storages. So for example, if one user has created the item Apple. When another user starts typing that in, they get a drop-down with the option to select the previously created Apple item from the other user. But while the name, description, image, and kcal might be the same, the amount and expiration date probably differ from user to user. Hence I put it in a pivot table.

Which went fine until I tried to run this Eloquent query:

```
$item = Items::find($id)->storageContent()->get();
```

Where `storageContent()` is a Eloquent relationship from the Items model:

```
public function storageContent(){

    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Items::class,'storage_contents','item_id','storage_id')
        ->withPivot('amount','expiry_date');

}
```

But for some reason, when I execute this query, I only get the data from the first table entry (regardless of what ID I put into the query), but the pivot table data **is** from the right pivot table. But I can't for the life of me figure out **why** this is happening.

To clarify what I am getting and what expect to get with this query:

When I put the query in Artisan tinker:

Say I have 2 items in my Items table:

```
|-------------------|-------------------|
|       items       |       items       |
|-------------------|-------------------|
|       id: 1       |       id: 2       |
|-------------------|-------------------|
|     name: foo     |     name: bar     |
|-------------------|-------------------|
| description: null | description: null |
|-------------------|-------------------|
|    kcal: null     |    kcal: null     |
|-------------------|-------------------|
|   img_url: null   |   img_url: null   |
|-------------------|-------------------|
| always_on_list: 0 | always_on_list: 0 |
|-------------------|-------------------|
```

where foo has a amount of 123 and bar has a amount of 321.

When I enter `$item = Items::find(1)->storageContent()->get();` into Artisan tinker, I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#109
 all: [
   App\Items {#2337
     id: 1,
     name: "test1",
     description: "foo",
     kcal: null,
     img_url: null,
     always_on_list: 0,
     created_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     updated_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2332
       item_id: 1,
       storage_id: 1,
       amount: 123,
       expiry_date: null,
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

Which is in line with what I expect to get, but when I do `$item = Items::find(2)->storageContent()->get();`, I get:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#109
 all: [
   App\Items {#2337
     id: 1,
     name: "test1",
     description: "foo",
     kcal: null,
     img_url: null,
     always_on_list: 0,
     created_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     updated_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2332
       item_id: 2,
       storage_id: 1,
       amount: 321,
       expiry_date: null,
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

Which is not what I expect to get, I expect to get:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#109
 all: [
   App\Items {#2337
     id: 2,
     name: "test2",
     description: "bar",
     kcal: null,
     img_url: null,
     always_on_list: 0,
     created_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     updated_at: "2018-06-24 15:12:03",
     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2332
       item_id: 2,
       storage_id: 1,
       amount: 321,
       expiry_date: null,
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

Maybe any of you have an idea of what I did wrong?

Comment: What is right pivot table? If you are talking i terms of eloquent tell me the table name or model name... Dont indicate directions for tables. Please spexify clearly what are getting from current query and what do you expect?

Comment: @Ruman I'm sorry, I have added a example of what I expect to get and what I'm actually getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not responding for a little while. I just looked at my problem/code once more, and found another solution that seems to solve my problem.

So, I had this relationship before in my `Items` model:

public function storageContent(){

```
return $this
    ->belongsToMany(Items::class,'storage_contents','item_id','storage_id')
    ->withPivot('amount','expiry_date');
}
```

But I think I misunderstood what rows I should've entered in there, cause `storage_id` as the related key doesn't make **any** sense (in retrospect). Cause if I change it just to `id` (aka the `id` row in the `Item` table), like this:

public function storageContent(){

```
return $this
    ->belongsToMany(Items::class,'storage_contents','item_id','id')
    ->withPivot('amount','expiry_date');
}
```

it works like I expect it to.

I would still like to thank everybody for trying to help me and trying to find a solutions for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Storage` model:

```
public function items() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Items::class,
        'storage_contents',
        'item_id',
        'storage_id'
    )->withPivot('amount','expiry_date'); 
}
```

And query:

```
$storage = Storage::where('id', $id)->with('items')->firstOrFail();
```

You can access pivot columns in your views as:

```
@foreach($storage->items as $item)
    <ul>
        <li>Amount - {{$item->pivot->amount}} </li>
        <li>Expiry - {{$item->pivot->expiry_date}} </li>
    </ul>
@enforeach
```

**UPDATE**

> I have just tried it out, it is not what I wanted. Maybe it helps if I explain where I need want to use this query. When the user is in the storage location, he/she can see what items are in that storage location. When the user clicks on a item, a modal needs to pop up and show the information of that item (name, description, kcal, amount, expiry date) to fill in that modal.

As you said in the comments when a user accesses an item in a storage, you want to show a modal with pivot colums. So, when a user first aceesses a storage, then you should probably get the `Storage` with all its items that way each item would have pivot columns. Maybe you want an inverse of what I gave you. You can see the changes above.

However, if you want only a single item from the storage then probably you already have `storage` or its `id`. Then, you might try this:

```
$storage = Storage::findOrFail($storageId)
```

Then you can get a single item by using this:

```
$items = $storage->items()->where('id', $itemId)->firstOrFail();
```

This might help you.

Comment: I don't want to get the information of the storage with this query, I want to get the item information and the information from the pivot table related to the item ID I give it.

Comment: Ok. When you post your question, please provide necessary details always. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my first question ever on StackOverflow. I will try to provide better information in the future.

Comment: Its Okay! I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have just tried it out, it is not what I wanted. Maybe it helps if I explain where I need want to use this query. When the user is in the storage location, he/she can see what items are in that storage location. When the user clicks on a item, a modal needs to pop up and show the information of that item (name, description, kcal, amount, expiry date) to fill in that modal.

Comment: In that case, if each item has its own `expiry_date`, then you should probably change your structure. `expiry_date` column should be on `items` table instead of `pivot`. Then you'd also be able to access the column directly on `item` without having to load relationship.

Comment: I would've normally done that. But because I intend items to be able to be used by different users across different storages, the amount and expiration date probably aren't gonna be the same. So that's why I put those in a separate pivot table (I have added this to the main question too now).

Comment: In this case you'll need `Storage::find($id)->with('items')->get()`. You definitely shouldn't load all items one by one.

Comment: This query is not used to get all items that are in a storage, this one is meant to get all the information of **one** item once the user has clicked on one of the items.